# Variable acts like pointer in Python?

Tags: python

I just came across what I find very strange behaviour that I would like to understand. Unfortunately I don't really know how to search for it.

If I have a function

```
def func(A, B):
    A_ = A
    A_[0, 1] = A_[0, 1] + 1
```

and a dictionary

```
dicto = {"A": np.zeros((3,3))} .
```

Now calling the function with `func(dicto["A"])` will cause the array stored in the dictionary dicto to be changed. This is similar to a pointer, but I thought pointers don't exist in Python?

Why is that the case? I would expect `A_` to be a local variable, meaning any change applied to it shouldn't affect the variable stored in the dictionary.

This behaviour changes to what I expected when the function is changed to

```
def func(A, B):
    A_ = A * 1
    A_[0, 1] = A_[0, 1] + 1 .
```

How can I achieve what I want without the extra calculation of `A * 1`?

Comment: You want a deep copy of your object, am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly what a deep copy is. I want to create a copy of the original, change an entry in that matrix, use it for a calculation and then discard it again afterwards. What would be the best way to do that? How can I avoid passing by reference?

Comment: You can't. Objects in Python are passed by reference

Comment: Just as an update, I found a numpy function that does this for me: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html

Comment: It's however a lot slower: %timeit z = x*1
931 ns ± 7.83 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each) | 
%timeit z = np.copy(x)
2.26 µs ± 40.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)